# ASP.NET Core how to pass parameter in service builder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I've read a very useful [article](https://michael-mckenna.com/multi-tenant-asp-dot-net-core-application-tenant-resolution/) from Michael McKenna blog about creating a multi-tenant application but I've a couple of issues.
The first one in the *TenantMiddleware* class as *Constants.HttpContextTenantKey* is undefined, it's likely due to some missing code, I've set a constant string in the meantime.

The main issue is that I'd like to pass the tenants array in the *InMemoryTenantStore* class when I call the service at startup. I've modified the *InMemoryTenantStore* class

```
 public class InMemoryTenantStore : ITenantStore<Tenant>
{
    private readonly Tenant[] _tenants;
    public InMemoryTenantStore(Tenant[] tenants)
    {
        _tenants = tenants;
    }
```

but I don't have idea how to pass the array in the calling service. I guess I need to tweak this code

```
 public TenantBuilder<T> WithStore<V>(ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient) where V : class, ITenantStore<T>
    {
        _services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(typeof(ITenantStore<T>), typeof(V), lifetime));
        return this;
    }
```

But I can't find any example about this and unfortunately I can't reach the author blog.

Comment: any update on the 'Constants.HttpContextTenantKey' undefined error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating object instances through `ServiceDescriptor` with parameters you must to provide **implementation factory** to it, not just implementation type.

You can do this two ways:

1. Just create instance directly before `WithStore` method.
2. Create implementation factory for build `TenantBuilder` (using lambda or separate method)

```cs
// Creating instance outside
public TenantBuilder<T> WithStore<V>(V store, ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient) where V : class, ITenantStore<T>
{
    _services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(typeof(ITenantStore<T>), provider => store, lifetime));
    return this;
}

// Implementation factory
public TenantBuilder<T> WithStore<V>(Func<IServiceProvider, V> implementationFactory, ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient) where V : class, ITenantStore<T>
{
    _services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Describe(typeof(ITenantStore<T>), implementationFactory, lifetime));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've modified the _TenantBuilder_ as specified in the first solution and I change the code in _Startup.cs_ this way:
`            services.AddMultiTenancy()
                .WithResolutionStrategy<HostResolutionStrategy>()
                .WithStore<InMemoryTenantStore>(new InMemoryTenantStore(tenants));
`
I don't get any errors but the application is frozen.

Comment: @g.lorenzo I believe that it's not by code in answer. You can check your application execution path by pause it while debugging to see where app freezing.

Comment: You're right @picolino, the app is freezing for another reason, I took a while to figure it out as debugging was useless. Your solution works like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

this is what I did

```
public class Constants
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, object> HttpContextTenantKey { get; private set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
```

Comment: How does this solve problem from question? Please provide more context.

Comment: That is to resolve the missing/undefined HttpContextTenantKey from the said blog.